# How to give multiple columns as primary key in entity - JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities - Course, Module, Timeline
In the timeline entity - I want to give 2 keys as primary key i.e Composite Key. How am I supposed to give that. Please tell me about the changes that are to be done in the code below:

Course:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
Integer courseId;
@Column(name = "course_name")
String course_name;
```

Module:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "module_id")
Integer module_id;
@Column(name = "module_type")
String module_type;
@Column(name = "module_name")
String module_name;
@Column(name = "duration")
Integer duration;
@OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Course course;
```

Timeline:

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "timeline_id")
    Integer timeline_id;
    @ManyToOne( cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
    private Module module;
    @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Course course;
```

Now here in timeline, I want to have **course_id** and **timeline_id** as primary keys. Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Update:
I tried using Embeddable and EmbeddedId:

```
@Embeddable
public class TimelineId implements Serializable{
    private Integer course_id;
    private Integer timelineId;
    getters and setters
    hashcode and equals
}
```

**Module:**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "timeline")
public class Timeline {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TimelineId timelinepk;
    @ManyToOne( cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
    private Module module;
    @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Course course;
    
}
```

But this gives an error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.scb.axess.playbook.model.Timeline
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: I will recommend you not to use composite primary keys, it will make things way more difficult later on compared to simple, synthetic primary keys. There are cases where composite keys are justified, but as I see it, this case is not among them. BR

Comment: Do you need the `timeline_id` in your `timeline`-entity? So: Should the primary key should be `(timeline_id, module, course)` or just `(module, course)`?

Comment: @ApoorvaOjha Look at the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite). You can find a loot of examples here.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple possibilities to solve your problem:

**Possibility 1: Using `IdClass`**

*Defining the `IdClass` type*

This class has to implement the `Serializable` interface and the `equals(..)` and `hashCode()` methods. The class holds the parts of the composite primary key.

```
public class TimelineId implements Serializable  {

    private Integer timelineId;
    private Integer courseId;

    // getters & setters

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // your impl of hashCode
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // your impl of equals
    }

}
```

*Modify your `Timeline` class*

Here the `@IdClass` annotation is added to the entity class. Further, the class holds the same fields like the `IdClass` type (name and type should be identical), but annotated with `@Id`.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TimelineId.class)
public class Timeline {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "timeline_id")
    private Integer timelineId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private Integer courseId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "module_id")
    private Module module;

    // getters & setters

}
```

**Possibility 2: Using `EmbeddedId`**

*Defining the `EmbeddedId` type*

This class also holds the parts of the composite primary key.

```
@Embeddable
public class TimelineId {

    @Column(name = "timeline_id")
    private Integer timelineId;
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private Integer courseId;

    // getters & setters

}
```

*Modify your `Timeline` class*

In this case the single parts of the composite primary key can be omitted. Only a field of the embedded key type annotated with `@EmbeddedId` is defined.

```
@Entity
public class Timeline {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TimelineId timelineId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "module_id")
    private Module module;

    // getters & setters

}
```

In both cases the corresponding repositories should be defined like this (`TimelineId` has to be used for parameter type `ID`) (here, `JpaRepository` is used):

```
public interface TimelineRepository extends JpaRepository<Timeline, TimelineId> {}
```

**Possibility 3: Don't use a composite PK, but make the columns unique**

*Modify your `Timeline` class*

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "course_id", "module_id"
    })
})
public class Timeline {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "timeline_id")
    Integer timeline_id;
    @ManyToOne( cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "module_id)
    private Module module;
    @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id)
    private Course course;

    // getters & setters

}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for taking out your time..I want the timeline_id and course_id as primary keys. Will the above solution work for the same?

Comment: For the third possibility, the timeline_id can be same and repeating and hence it cannot be a primary key alone. :(

Comment: I changed my answer. I mixed up the primary key parts (I assumed that the key consists of `course_id` and `module_id` and not `timeline_id` and `course_id`)